# How to show $[0,1]×[0,1]$ remove three points is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, quotient-spaces

How to show $I^2=[0,1]×[0,1]$ remove three points is connected ?

I am sure $X=I^2\backslash\{a,b,c\}$ is path connected hence connected for any $a,b,c \in I^2$, but I am not sure how to find the actual continuous path for any two points in $X$. Or is there any other method I can use to show $X$ is connected? Thanks a lot!

Comment: choose loops around every of those 3 pts small enough s.t. they don't intersect. Now between any $x,y$ you can choose a linear path. Either this gives you a well defined path or it meets one (or more) of the points, in which case you just go around the loop and continue afterwards.

Comment: For each $x$ and $y$ in $X$, choose four paths connecting $x$ to $y$ in $I^2$ and which never meet except at $x$ and $y$. Then at least one of these paths meets neither $a$ nor $b$ nor $c$ hence it connects $x$ to $y$ in $X$. The approach works to show that $I^2$ minus any finite number of points is path connected hence connected. Each path can be a part of a circle passing by $x$ and $y$ and some given point on the perpendicular bisector of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Dan: Your proof doesn't allow for the case when $x$ or $y$ is inside one of the loops. But it's easy to fix $-$ just choose the loops _after_ you are given $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to actually find the path - if it's pathconnected then it's connected, no matter what paths are used.

However, you could do the following: given any two points, draw a straight line between them. If that line is invalid because one of the $a, b, c$ is on it, then take a detour by using two straight lines through some corner point instead. (There is a valid detour: there are infinitely many possible detours, but each removed point invalidates precisely one detour if you take the corner point to be equidistant from the two points.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that if there exists a punctured neighborhood $\Omega_p\subseteq C$ of a point $p\in C$ then the set $C\setminus\{p\}$ is connected if $C$ is connected.

To see how this helps let's assume that you picked away $p_1, ... p_{n-1}$ from $I^2$ without disconnecting it and we have a distinct $p_n\in I^2$ (if it's not distinct removing it will do no difference), we know that for a punctured disc of radius $r$ we have that $D_{p_n;r} \cap I^2$ is connected. Now we can choose $r$ so that the punctured disc doesn't cover any of the other points and thereby $D_{p_n;r} \cap I^2 \subseteq I^2\setminus \{p_1, ... p_{n-1}\}$.

Now for the proof of the lemma that's used. Assume that $C\setminus\{p\}$ is not connected, then we have to open disjoint sets $U$ and $V$ such that $C\setminus\{p\} = U \cup V$, but now $\Omega_p\cap V$ and $\Omega_p\cap U$ are open and disjoint sets and their union is $\Omega_p\cap(U\cup V) = \Omega_p\cap(C\setminus\{p\}) = \Omega_p$, but that contradicts the fact that $\Omega_p$ is connected.